# Fubini's theorem for transition kernels

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-probability, fubini-tonelli-theorems

In probability theorey there is a different form of Fubini's theorem that includes Markov kernels (regular conditional distributions) that does not need independence. Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, \mathbb{P})$ be a probability space and $X:\Omega \rightarrow \mathcal{X}$ and $Y:\Omega \rightarrow \mathcal{Y}$  random variables. Then for a function $f:\mathcal{X}\times\mathcal{Y}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that is either non-negative and measurable or integrable, the theorem is expressed as
$$\int_{\mathcal{X}\times\mathcal{Y}}f(x,y)\mathbb{P}(d(x,y)) = \int_{\mathcal{X}}\biggl(\int_{\mathcal{Y}}f(x, y) \mathbb{P}_{Y\mid X}(dy, x)\biggl)\mathbb{P}_X(dx).$$

My question is if, like in the original theorem by Fubini, it is possible to change the order of integration, i.e., to first integrate over $y$ and then over $x$?

More specifically what I mean here is, if it is possible that we first view the conditional distribution as a measurable function on $\mathcal{X}$ for a fixed set $dy$ and then after integrating over $x$ we view it as a measure on $\mathcal{Y}$?

I am not sure how to write this formally, but something like this:
$$
\int_{\mathcal{Y}}\biggl(\int_{\mathcal{X}}f(x, y) \mathbb{P}_X(dx)\mathbb{P}_{Y\mid X}(dy, x)\biggl)
$$
Is this possible? Maybe yes under certain conditions?

Comment: The order of integration does not play a role here, as we have the same assumptions on $X$ and $Y$. Simply renaming $X$ to be $Y$ and $Y$ to be $X$ yields that the same equality holds with different order of integration.

Comment: but the Markov kernel (regular conditional distribution) is not "symmetric" in its arguments. I.e., in the first argument (a set) it is a probability distribution (for each fixed x in the second argument) and in the second argument it is a measurable function for each fixed set in the first argument....

Comment: So if we first integrate over "x" we get a different behaviour because we actually integrate over the function $f(x, y) \mathbb{P}_{Y\mid X}(dy, x)$ for $dy$ fixed. If we integrate over $y$ we just integrate over $f(x, y)$.

Comment: we can't fix $\mathrm dy$, it is a placeholder for integration over a certain space

Comment: Thanks, so what does it mean then for the interchanging of the order of integration? Can I first integrate over  Y and then X or equivalently first over X and then Y? Or is this wrong?

Comment: So isnt Lemma 2.3 in 
https://msp.org/pjm/1972/41-1/pjm-v41-n1-p04-p.pdf
saying what I was asking for? Or does it mean something different? I.e., this Lemma seems to imply that I can first integrate over the marginal and then over the conditional, no?

Comment: @SBF but if we first integrate the inner integral over $y$ then we also assume that the outter integral over $x$ is fixed, no? I.e., that $dx$ is fixed first. More generally, what do you mean by your answer? That given a conditional distribution of $Y$ given$ X=x$ we cannot first view $\mathbb{P}_{Y=x}(dy)$ as the measure argument being evaluated on the set $dy$ and hence we can simply view it as a measurable function in $x$?

Answer (score 1):

It would be more clear when you consider two discrete random variables. Suppose $X,Y$ have p.m.f $p(x,y)$. Then we have $E[f(x,y)]=\sum_{x,y} p(x)p(y|x)f(x,y)$. Summing $y$ first and then $x$, we have $E[f(x,y)]=\sum_x(p(x)\sum_yp(y|x)f(x,y))$, the genral case of which is the one you first mentioned. However you can see it makes no sense to sum $x$ first in $p(x)p(y|x)f(x,y)$. The only way to sum $x$ first is to write $p(x,y)=p(y)p(x|y)f(x,y)$, but it still finds the conditional expectation first.

In conclusion you cannot integrate over the marginal first and then over the conditional distribution.

Comment: hi why doesnt it make sense to sum first over the $x$?

Comment: @guest1 The three terms $p(x),p(y|x),f(x,y)$ all depend on $x$, so there is no direct simplification for $\sum_x p(x)p(y|x)f(x,y)$.

Comment: but just because there is no direct simplification possible doesnt mean that it is not allowed to do right? So I would still be allowed to integrate over the marginal and after that integrating over the conditional?

Comment: @guest1 "no direct simplification" actually  means that you find it impossible to write $\sum_x p(x)p(y|x)f(x,y)$ in the form of expectation wrt $X$. Or you can think it in another way: If you take marginal expectation wrt $X$ first then the result will not contain any $X$, then the conditional expectation $E(\cdot|X)$ makes no sense.

Comment: Why can I not write it as $\mathbb{E}_X[p(y|x)f(x,y)]$ ?

Comment: can you maybe elaborate on that? because for any fixed y, p(y|x) is merely a measurable function so I could certainly write $\mathbb{E}_X[p(y|x)]$. In fact this is nothing else than marginalization: $p(y) = \sum_x p(y|x) p(x) = \mathbb{E}_X[p(y|x)]$. So I dont understand why it should not be possible to write this as an expectation?

Comment: @guest1This is not "simplification" as I mean. The meaningful simplification should involve only $f$. To be specific, the expectation of $f(x,y)$ is a double sum $\sum_{x,y}p(x,y)f(x,y)$. By transforming it properly, it is possible to calculate it simply by means of an iterated sum, i.e., first we find the conditional expectation of $f$ and then marginal expectation. This is meaningful simplification because we find the conditional expectation of $f$ instead of $E(f)$.

Comment: On the other hand, the result obtained from $\sum_x p(x)p(y|x)f(x,y)$ is a function of $y$ and has nothing to do with $x$. How can you write the sum of it over $y$ as a conditional expectation?

Answer (score 0):

The equality:
$$\int_{\mathcal{X}}\biggl(\int_{\mathcal{Y}}f(x, y) d\mathbb{P}_{Y/X=x}(y)\biggl)d\mathbb{P}_X(x) = \int_{\mathcal{Y}}\biggl(\int_{\mathcal{X}}f(x, y) d\mathbb{P}_X(x)\biggl)d\mathbb{P}_{Y/X=x}(y).$$
doesn't make sense, unless $X$ and $Y$ are independent: the right-hand side depends on $x$, the first does not.

Comment: So does that mean that the order of integratin cannot be exchanged?

Comment: The way to exchange the order would be:
$\int_{\mathcal{X}}\biggl(\int_{\mathcal{Y}}f(x, y) d\mathbb{P}_{Y/X}\biggl)d\mathbb{P}_X=\int_{\mathcal{Y}}\biggl(\int_{\mathcal{X}}f(x, y) d\mathbb{P}_{X/Y}\biggl)d\mathbb{P}_Y.$

Comment: And this is allowed and the same? How can you prove that?

Comment: The above is nothing more than the expression in integral form of the well-known one: $E[E[f(X,Y)|X]]=E[E[f(X,Y)|Y]]=E[f( X,Y)]$.

Comment: Ok but what you have been doing is exchanging the conditioning. But what i meant is the following: instead of first integrating over the Kernel and after that over the marginal measure, can you first integrate over the marginal measure and then over the kernel

Comment: @Christophe Leuridan. Thanks, but it was better as it was, and I would appreciate it if you undid the change.
​

Comment: Once the arguments of $f$ are specified, the integration variables should be specified also.

Comment: @Christophe Leuridan. Could I then write $\int_{\mathcal{X}}\biggl(\int_{\mathcal{Y}}f(x, y) d\mathbb{P}_{Y/X=y}(x) \biggl)d\mathbb{P}_X(y)$?

Comment: No, because $x$ would vary in $\mathcal{Y}$ and $y$ in $\mathcal{X}$, so you would have to integrate $f(y,x)$.

Comment: @Christophe Leuridan. Then, if the expression $\int_{\mathcal{X}}\biggl(\int_{\mathcal{Y}}f(x, y) d\mathbb{P}_{Y/X}\biggl)d\mathbb{P}_X$ is not ambiguous, why complicate it?

Comment: Then you should write $f$ instead of $f(x,y)$. Moreover, is it clear for everybody what is denoted by $P_{Y|X}$? It could be also « the »  $\sigma(X)$-measurable random probability on $\mathcal{Y}$ such that for every measurable bounded function $h : \mathcal{Y} \to \mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{E}[h(Y)|\sigma(X)] = \int_{\mathcal{Y}} h dP_{Y|X}$.

Comment: @Christophe Leuridan. In that case the expression would be absurd and we would have to write:$\int_{\mathcal{\Omega}}\biggl(\int_{\mathcal{Y}}f(X,y) d\mathbb{P}_{Y/ X}\biggl)d\mathbb{P}_{\Omega}$

Comment: If the dependence with regard to $x$ appears in $f(x,y)$, it should also appear in $dP_{Y|X=x}$.

Comment: https://people.ece.cornell.edu/zivg/ECE_5630_Lectures4.pdf

hi in this lecture notes, theorem 1 (at the very end of the pdf) the lecturer says that in equality (b) he used the funbini tonelli theorem. So he is excatly doing what I was asking in my question: In the equality (a) the inner integral is over $\mathcal{X}$, i.e., in the inner integral he would integrate over the marginal measure, and then in the outer integral he would then integrate over the conditional measure. So is this wrong what he is doing there?

Comment: Equality (a) does not make sense. What does it mean to integrate $d\mathbb{P}_{Y/X}$ with respect to $\mathbb{P}_X$? It could be understood as the resulting measure of the integral: $\int \mathbb{P}_{Y/X}d\mathbb{P}_X$, but $\mathbb{P}_{Y/X}$ is a function of $X$ in $\mathscr{M}$, the set of measures over $Y$, a space of infinite dimensions. In order to integrate this type of functions, it would first be necessary to give $\mathscr{M}$, at least, a Banach space structure. So in those notes the author would have to clarify what he means by that type of integral.

Comment: So are there cases where it would be possible to do that integration? I dont quite understand your argument with the infinite dimensional space. I.e., why this should be a problem?

Comment: also regarding the right hand side of the equation in your answer. You say that it depends on $x$. But what if we would have integrated over the $x$ part of the conditional distribution when integrating the inner integral over $x$. I.e., first view the conditional distribution as a measure function of $x$ for some fixed set over $\mathcal{Y}$ (it would be the infinitesimal dy), and after that integrate over dy?

Comment: I think this is all a bit confusing. It seems like you don't have clear ideas. I propose that you give a simple and concrete example where you express what you want to say.